# jQuery show div if no results

Tags: jquery

I have a live search script ([JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/byxq9/)) which I need to add a error message to.

Basically I need to check:

- if the search box has 1 or more characters
- that there are no search results available

Current code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[name=filter]').attr('autocomplete','off');
  $("#filter").keyup(function(){
   $('#search-content').show();
   var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;
   $(".item li").each(function(){
    if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0 || filter == '') {
     $(this).hide();
    } else {
     $(this).show();
     count++;
    }
   });
  });
 });
```

Any guidance on a function which will do this for me is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/byxq9/12/)**

Check Length of value in the textbox.

```
if(filter.length >= 1){
     alert('1 or more')
}
```

---

Check if there aren't any results from the search.

```
if(!$('li:visible').length){
     alert('no results');
}
```

---

Final code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name=filter]').attr('autocomplete', 'off');

    $("#filter").keyup(function () {

        var filter = $(this).val(),
            count = 0;
        if (filter.length >= 1) {
            alert('1 or more')
        }

        $(".country li").each(function () {
            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                $(this).fadeOut();
            } else {
                $(this).show();
                $('#call-content').show();
                count++;
            }
        });
        if (!$('li:visible').length) {
            alert('no results');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: shouldn't you wrap the `each` and last `if` inside `if (filter.length >= 1)`?

Comment: yes, that would make no difference, but it is a sort of validation

Comment: Partly working - http://jsfiddle.net/byxq9/9/ - the error message shows on 0 input (needs to be at least one character) and the error doesn't show on no results... any help would be appreciated

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/byxq9/12/. Working now. YOu need two separate `if`. As filter in counted on keyup and `li` is counter after `.each`

Comment: Perfecto, thanks so much, as a side question, how do stop the search content from appearing for less than 3 characters e.g. someone has to search for ger for germany to appear etc :)

Comment: There you go final update http://jsfiddle.net/byxq9/13/ . Add a condition `if(filter.length >=3)`